# I have a trouble adding a path for my cross compiler

Tags: bash, shell

I'm having a problem adding a path of my cross compiler to path so that the cross compiler is automatically loaded to be used when the system boots. Here is my code in .profile.

```
if [ "$BASH" ]; then
  if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
    . ~/.bashrc
  fi
fi

PATH=$PATH:/home/taki/ti-processor-sdk-linux-am57xx-evm-05.02.00.10/linux-devkit/sysroots/x86_64-arago-linux/usr/bin/
export PATH
export CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-linux-gnueabihf-

mesg n || true
```

and I type

```
source ~/.profile
```

to  apply the updated path. But I don't see my path changed after I type 'export'

```
declare -x PATH="/home/taki/arago-2011.09/armv5te/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin"
```

The path hasn't been updated as you can see. 
Can anyone point out what I'm missing?

Comment: What have you done to debug this?

Comment: I haven't done much to debug since I don't know where to start from. But my friend suggested me to type './etc/profile' on root user. After entering the command, I can see the path changed now but only when the user is root. I want the path to be applied to whatever user I'm on.